# Fingerprint identification SDK

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, fingerprint

I am looking for a fingerprint identification SDK to use with a C# project.

I have a list of paper forms that have a the applicants' fingerprints in a specified area and I need to eliminate duplicate forms (forms with identical fingerprints). The paper forms will be scanned using a high speed scanner. I need an SDK to do 1-to-many matching with the other forms fingerprints.

Most SDKs I found only accept input from a fingerprint scanner. Is there any fingerprint SDK that can accept scanned fingerprint images (e.g. in TIFF format).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [VeriFinger SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html)

It can handle what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Download the C# sdk version from the following [link](http://www.files.com/set/5205aeeb584ce). It has a CTK_DLL API  you can use for fingerprint handling.